# Android layout is off. need to fix position

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I would like the layout on the right to match the layout on the left in terms of the text boxes that have the '20' in them. The one on the left is where I would like it to be but the one on the right will not position correctly. I would also like to have a small spinner in the top right corner above the 20

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/history1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:text="This is where life histroy goes" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/playerLifeOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/badd1"
       android:layout_width="78dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="+1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/badd5"
           android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bsub1"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bsub5"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/playerLifeTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="40dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2add1"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2add5"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2sub1"
           android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2sub5"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-5" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share an image? Would be easy to understand what you are looking for;)

Comment: This is what you have now. I wonder what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like image below, you can use (your modified) layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/history1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
                android:text="This is where life histroy goes" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerLifeOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="40dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/badd1"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/badd5"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+5" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bsub1"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bsub5"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerLifeTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="40dp" >
                <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
                <Spinner 
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2add1"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2add5"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+5" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2sub1"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2sub5"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Change #2 to match #1 :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/playerLifeTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```